# Password check in Python

Tags: python, string, loops

I have my code and i'm almost done its just that i have to make the program say invalid password if there is a symbol in it. . . .

```
password = input("Enter password to test: ")

caps = sum(1 for c in password if c.isupper())
lower = sum(1 for c in password if c.islower())
nums = sum(1 for c in password if c.isnumeric())

r = [caps, lower, nums]

if len(password) < 8: 
    if caps >= 1:
        if lower >= 1:
            if nums >= 1:
                print("Valid Passeord")
            elif nums < 1:
                print("Invalid password")
        elif lower < 1:
            print("Invalid password")
    elif caps < 1:
        print("Invalid password")
```

And just for an added bonus how would i make it rerun if its and invalid password?

```
password = input("Enter password to test: ")

caps = sum(1 for c in password if c.isupper())
lower = sum(1 for c in password if c.islower())
nums = sum(1 for c in password if c.isnumeric())

r = [caps, lower, nums]

if not password.isalnum(): # use .isalpha() if you don't want digits in your password
    print("Invalid password")
    if len(password) < 8: 
        if caps >= 1:
            if lower >= 1:
                if nums >= 1:
                    print("Valid password")
                elif nums < 1:
                    print("Invalid password")
            elif lower < 1:
                print("Invalid password")
        elif caps < 1:
            print("Invalid password")
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add what the code is currently doing.  Is it not behaving as you would expect?

Comment: ideally, you should have done one way encryption of all your password...say using `sha1` and compare its `hexdigest`.That would solve all your problems!

Answer (score 2):

By symbol, I'm assuming you mean anything except for letters and numbers?

```
# Initialize our valid flag
valid = False

while not valid:
    # Grab password and count everything as your original code
    password = input("Please enter password: ")
    caps = sum(1 for c in password if c.isupper())
    lower = sum(1 for c in password if c.islower())
    nums = sum(1 for c in password if c.isnumeric())

    # If password is not alphanumeric (contains symbols) or shorter than 8 characters, it's not valid
    if not password.isalnum() or len(password) < 8:
        valid = False

    # Otherwise, the password is only valid if everything occurs at least once
    else:
        valid = all(x >= 1 for x in (caps, lower, nums))

    # Check if your password is valid, and if it is, print valid and break out of the loop
    if valid:
        print("Valid Password")
        break
    # Otherwise, print invalid and the loop goes on
    else:
        print("Invalid Password")
```

Comment: I did that and now if i enter in just "password" nothing prompts this is what i have

Comment: no as long as its 8 characters, only digits and letters, have to have 1 digit, and no symbols im good

Comment: @MosesSaygbe so all you want is 8  characters (only digits and letters and must have 1 digit)? What about upper/lower case?

Comment: oh thanks i for got that have to have atleast one  upper and one lower. it all worked for me it just when i put you line in thats when it didnt.

Comment: try out my edited version (also supports multiple attempts). Replace everything with what I posted - the earlier suggestion had a mistake, extra indentation wasn't needed, but the later edit takes care of all that.

Comment: @MosesSaygbe let me know if that works, and I can walk you through what I'm doing.

Comment: could you walk me through it cause its still giving me invalid password for like 1Password

Comment: yes it can ! can be as long as it wants would i just change the len part

Comment: @MosesSaygbe alright, see my edited answer, I also added explanations. Let me know if something is still unclear.